# How to run for loop on different groups in R

Tags: r, loops, group-by

I have designed a for loop that refers to the previous record in the calculation.

```
for(j in 2:nrow(fd1))){
    fd1$c[j]=((fd1$c[j-1]+fd1$outflow[j])/(1+fd1$discount_rate[j]))-fd1$inflow[j]
  }
```

I have grouped the data frame using the group_by statement from Dplyr package and now want to execute this loop on different groups. Also, it will be very helpful if someone can explain me how to execute the loop with pipes

Thank you for your help

Comment: Without using loops `((fd1$c[1:(nrow(fd1)-1)]+fd1$outflow[2:nrow(fd1)]/(1+fd1$discount_rate[2:nrow(fd1)])))-fd1$inflow[2:nrow(fd1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for loops are not needed:

```
fd1 <- fd1 %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(c = (lag(c) + outflow)/(1+discount_rate)-inflow) %>%
filter(!is.na(c)) # if you want to remove resulting NAs (because of lag)
```

Comment: Thank You Luminita, but what if I want to keep the first value of each group fixed or perform some other calculation should I just replace NA with that calculation

Comment: Then instead of replacing `c` with the new computed values, you may create another feature (within `mutate`), say `new_c_feature`. Then, you can replace NAs by another formula using the initial values from the `c` column.